# pass id to calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

When tabbing the accessory button, i need to pass the itemId, so i can identify the item to pass on to my detail view.

So far:

Add the annotations:

```
for (id row in self.detailItem) {
    Item *i = (Item *) row; 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destination;
    destination.latitude = (double) i.latitude;
    destination.longitude = (double) i.longitude;

    //i.itemid

    MapViewAnnotation *destinationAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle: i.name andCoordinate: destination];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation: destinationAnnotation];     
    [destinationAnnotation release];
}
```

Add the accessory button

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
    pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
        pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

}

return pinAnnotation;
}
```

find the item to pass to detail view

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
// get annotation details here.

NSLog(@"%@", control);
}
```

Comment: can you provide me details of MapViewAnnotation. I need content of MapViewAnnotation.h & MapViewAnnotation.m

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add an `itemid` property to the `MapViewAnnotation` class.

When adding the annotation, set the property before calling `addAnnotation`:

```
destinationAnnotation.itemid = i.itemid;
[self.mapView addAnnotation: ...
```

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, access the annotation details like this:

```
MapViewAnnotation *annotationTapped = (MapViewAnnotation *)view.annotation;
NSLog(@"annotationTapped.itemid = %@", annotationTapped.itemid);
```

(If `itemid` will be an `int`, change the `%@` in the NSLog to `%d`.)

Comment: Didn't notice before but in your viewForAnnotation method, you need to set the annotation if view is being re-used.  So it should be: `if (pinAnnotation == nil) ... else pinAnnotation.annotation = annotation;`  Otherwise, an annotation that gets a re-used view may be pointing to the wrong annotation.